# Trying to set a cookie established on a web session as a header back to API

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I am trying to login via the webfront end and trying to intercept a cookie and then using that in the subsequent API request. I am having trouble getting the cookie back into the GET request. Code posted below.

```
import https from 'https';
import { bitbucketUser } from "../userRole.js"
import { ClientFunction } from 'testcafe';

fixture `Request/Response API`
 //   .page `https://myurl.company.com/login`
    .beforeEach(async t => {
        await t.useRole(bitbucketUser)
});

    test('test', async t => {
        const getCookie = ClientFunction(() => {
            return document.cookie;
        });
        var mycookie = await getCookie()

        const setCookie = ClientFunction(mycookie => {
            document.cookie = mycookie;
        });

        var validatecookie = await getCookie()
        console.log(validatecookie)
        const executeRequest = () => {    
            return new Promise(resolve => {

                const options = {
                    hostname: 'myurl.company.com',
                    path: '/v1/api/policy',
                    method: 'GET',
                    headers: {
                        'accept': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
                        'content-type': 'application/json' 
                    }
                };

                const req = https.request(options, res => {
                    console.log('statusCode:', res.statusCode);
                    console.log('headers:', res.headers);


                    let body = "";

                    res.on("data", data => {
                        body += data;
                      });

                    res.on("end", () => {
                        body = JSON.parse(body);
                        console.log(body);
                      });

                    resolve();
                });

                req.on('error', e => {
                    console.error(e);
                });

                req.end();
            });
        };      

        await setCookie(mycookie)
        await executeRequest();
    });
```

I have tried several examples but am quite not able to figure what is it that I am missing.

Answer (score 0):

When you call the `setCookie` method, you modify cookies in your browser using the ClientFunction.
 However, when you call your `executeRequest` method, you run it on the server side using the nodejs library. When you set cookies on the client, this will not affect your request sent from the server side. You need to add cookie information directly to your `options` object as described in the following thread: [How do I create a HTTP Client Request with a cookie?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4579757/how-do-i-create-a-http-client-request-with-a-cookie/23056332#23056332).

Answer (score 0):

In TestCafe v1.20.0 and later, you can send HTTP requests in your tests using the [`t.request`](https://testcafe.io/documentation/403981/reference/test-api/testcontroller/request) method. You can also use the [`withCredentials` option](https://testcafe.io/documentation/403971/guides/intermediate-guides/api-testing#receive-credentials) to attach all cookies to a request.

Please also note that TestCafe also offers a [cookie management API](https://testcafe.io/403938/release-notes/framework/2022-05-26-testcafe-v1-19-0-released#cookie-management) to set/get/delete cookies including `HTTPOnly`.